# MonoDevelop can't find .so file in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, linux-mint, monodevelop, lua

I'm making a game using MonoGame and a Linux implementation of LuaInterface.  However, whenever I try to build the project, MonoDevelop gives an error saying that it is unable to load `liblua5.1.so`, which is a library used by LuaInterface.  However, that file is absolutely in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `.bashrc` to include the directory where all the libraries are, and even after restarting that library is consistently in the path.  Any ideas why MonoDevelop would be unable to find this file?

(I'm using Linux Mint, by the way)

Comment: Did you check that this library has the same bitness than your mono engine?